# JVM -verbose : Formatting out put

Tags: java, java-6

I am analyzing the memory  usage of my java application and -verbose is added to jvm params. It prints many logs and difficult to read all of them. I am looking a for a way to format or get the output in a useful and readable way. I want to get the memory allocation, memory usage,free memory and jvm other useful info which can be useful to track memory leak . I use java 7

Comment: Have you tried JConsole?

Comment: [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) is what you want and is included in the jdk. Sadly your question is more about a recommendation and will probably end being closed.

Comment: are you on linux? jmap is nice

Comment: @j.con. Thanks. I ll have a look

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau. Thanks for your answer.. I m trying on it.. I think my question doesn't ask any recommendation but how... a way..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried mission controll?
You can see the status of JVM in real time with this application.

here is the explain demo video for mission controll

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qytuEgVmhsI#action=share

You can download it and check manual here.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html

try it and have fun!